# ActivityNotFoundException thrown

Tags: activitynotfoundexception

In which of the following cases is the ActivityNotFoundException thrown?

(a). When the Target Activity when started Explicitly is not declared in 
AndroidMainfest.xml file

(b). When the Target Activity to be started fails to retrieve the incoming intent object

(c). When the Target Activity lacks the `<intent-filer>` tag inside the  `AndroidMainfest.xml`

(d). None of the above

Comment: This exception is thrown when a call to startActivity(Intent) or one of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute the given Intent. [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException)

Comment: So, it is thrown when the activity is not added in the manifest.xml (thus not found)